# How to compute this formula $\operatorname {E} ({\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})$

Tags: probability

I am learning the justification of [Sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance)

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\operatorname {E} [\sigma _{Y}^{2}]&=\operatorname {E} \left[{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_{i}-{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\right)^{2}\right] \quad (1.1)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\operatorname {E} \left[Y_{i}^{2}-{\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\sum _{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right ] \quad (1.2)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left[{\frac {n-2}{n}}\operatorname {E} [Y_{i}^{2}]-{\frac {2}{n}}\sum _{j\neq i}\operatorname {E} [Y_{i}Y_{j}]+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\sum _{k\neq j}^{n}\operatorname {E} [Y_{j}Y_{k}]+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\operatorname {E} [Y_{j}^{2}]\right] \quad (1.3)\\[5pt]\end{aligned}}}$$

it is easy to understand how equation (1.1) would conduct to equation (1.2)

i am trying to understand how equation (1.2) would conduct to equation (1.3)

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\operatorname {E} [\sigma _{Y}^{2}]&=\operatorname {E} \left[{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_{i}-{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\right)^{2}\right] \quad (1.1)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\operatorname {E} \left[Y_{i}^{2}-{\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\sum _{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right ] \quad (1.2)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} \left[ \operatorname {E}(Y_{i}^{2})- \operatorname {E} ({\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})+\operatorname {E}({\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\sum _{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})\right ] \quad (2.2)\\[5pt]
\end{aligned}}}$$

with [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) equation (1.2) would conduct to equation (2.2)

the question is, how to compute the second term inside the square brackets in equation (2.2)?

$$
\operatorname {E} ({\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $Y_i$'s are independent, so
$$
\mathbb{E}[\frac{2}{n} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j]
=\frac{2}{n}\mathbb{E}[Y_i \sum_{j\neq i} Y_j + Y_i^2]
=\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_j] + \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]\right)
=\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_j] + \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]\right)
$$
(independence was used in the last equality). You can in turn rewrite
$$
\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_j] = \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_j] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_i]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_i]\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y_j] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i]^2
$$
giving
$$
\mathbb{E}[\frac{2}{n} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j]
=\frac{2}{n}\left(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y_j] + \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]- \mathbb{E}[Y_i]^2\right)\,.
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer.  does "$_$ 's are independent" mean each element in $_$ is independent to each other?

Comment: It means that $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are mutually independent, (which happens when you sample i.i.d.). For what I wrote to hold, though, pairwise independence is enough (for all i,j, $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are jndependent from each other). @shi95