# how the left side of this formula $\mathbb{E}[Y_i \sum_{j\neq i} Y_j ] = \sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_j]$ conduct to the right side?

Tags: probability

i am learning this [justification](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3229970/649828)

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[\frac{2}{n} Y_i \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j] 
&=\frac{2}{n}\mathbb{E}[Y_i \sum_{j\neq i} Y_j + Y_i^2] \quad (1.1)\\
&=\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_j] + \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]\right)  \quad (1.2)\\
&=\frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_j] + \mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]\right) \quad (1.3)
\end{aligned}}}$$

i've understood most of this justification, except a part of equation (1.1) to (1.2)

$\mathbb{E}[Y_i \sum_{j\neq i} Y_j ] = \sum_{j\neq i}\mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_j]$

which rule or definition take $Y_i$ into $[Y_i Y_j]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, the distributive law of arithmetic gives following equation inside the square brackets
$$Y_i \sum_{j\neq i} Y_j = \sum_{j\neq i} Y_i Y_j$$

secondly, linearity of expectation gives following equation

$$\mathbb{E} [\sum_{j\neq i} Y_i Y_j] = \sum_{j\neq i} \mathbb{E} [Y_i Y_j]$$

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the distributive law of arithmetic.  $Y_i\times \sum=\sum Y_i\times$ terms in sum.

Comment: Well, and linearity of expectation.