# which rule or definition apply ${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned} \operatorname {E} [Y_{i}^{2}] = (\sigma ^{2}+\mu ^{2}) \quad (3.1) \end{aligned}}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am learning the justification of [Sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance)

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\operatorname {E} [\sigma _{Y}^{2}]&=\operatorname {E} \left[{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_{i}-{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\right)^{2}\right] \quad (1.1)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\operatorname {E} \left[Y_{i}^{2}-{\frac {2}{n}}Y_{i}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\sum _{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\right ] \quad (1.2)\\[5pt]
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left[{\frac {n-2}{n}}\operatorname {E} [Y_{i}^{2}]-{\frac {2}{n}}\sum _{j\neq i}\operatorname {E} [Y_{i}Y_{j}]+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\sum _{k\neq j}^{n}\operatorname {E} [Y_{j}Y_{k}]+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\operatorname {E} [Y_{j}^{2}]\right] \quad (1.3)\\
&={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left[{\frac {n-2}{n}}(\sigma ^{2}+\mu ^{2})-{\frac {2}{n}}(n-1)\mu ^{2}+{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}n(n-1)\mu ^{2}+{\frac {1}{n}}(\sigma ^{2}+\mu ^{2})\right] \quad (1.4)\\
&={\frac {n-1}{n}}\sigma ^{2}
\end{aligned}}}$$

that [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229961/649828) is discussing how equation (1.2) would conduct to equation (1.3)

in this post, i am trying to understand how equation (1.3) would conduct to equation (1.4)

It seems that the procedure contains following equation

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\operatorname {E} [Y_{i}^{2}] = (\sigma ^{2}+\mu ^{2}) \quad (3.1)
\end{aligned}}}$$

does equation (3.1) hold? if yes, which rule or definition apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\sigma^{2}=EY_i^{2}-(EY_i)^{2}=EY_i^{2}-\mu^{2}$. Just add $\mu^{2}$ to both sides.

Comment: If you have defined $\sigma^{2}$ as $E(Y_i-EY_i)^{2}$ you have to expand the square to get the formula I have used.

Comment: thanks for your answer. is $\sigma^2$ the variance of population or the variance of sample?

Comment: In (3.1) it is the variance of the population.

Comment: thanks for your kind explanation. is $^2$ the variance of population or the variance of sample in the procedure from (1.3) to (1.4)?

Comment: @shi95, Except for the very beginning, where the author used a bit unfortunate notation $\sigma_Y^2$ to denote the sample variance, every other appearance of $\sigma$ refers to the population variance $\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(Y_i)}$.

Answer (score -1):

the [Definition part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) of wiki you linked gives the answer